# Datatables - Prevent event bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

This issue is driving me nuts.

I have a modal inside a jquery DataTable.

The event keeps bubbling up to the main event listener even though I try and prevent the event propagation.

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "button", function (e) {
  let data = tbl.row($(this).parents('tr')).data()
  $("#link").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    ...
  })
})
```

Is there a better way to attach to this event? The challenge is passing the row data into the nested modal.

Comment: Generally best not use to use nested events.  Your stopProp event will only be attached after you click one time.  Simply move the `$("#link").on...` code to the same level as `$("#dataTable...` code.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped. I moved it to its own event listener and got the data directly from the DOM instead of the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the event listener to the same level as the $("dataTable") code instead of nesting the listeners:

```
$("#link").on("click", function () {
  let device = $("#device").text()
  let group = $("#change-group").val()
...
})
```